# post category and product based on category id into two different tables using angularjs

Tags: mysql, angularjs, node.js

Im very new to angularjs.
I have categorylist and productslist in my spinner.Categories and products are two different tables in my db as category_insert and product_insert respiectively.Now when i click on register categories and products have to post into thier respective tables based on "userid".However products are based on categoryids.How can i do it?TIA
   angular code:

```
(function () {
var app = angular.module('MyApp');
app.controller('ProductCtrl', function($scope, $location, $http, ProductService) {
    $scope.productregstr = function() {
        $http ({
            method : 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/onio/v1/categoriesinsert',
            data: $scope.category_insert
        });
        // $auth.productregstr($scope.category_insert)
        //     .then(function(response) {
        //         toastr.info('You have successfully created a new account, Please Login');
        //     })
        //     .catch(function(response) {
        //         toastr.error(response.data.message);
        //     });
    };
    $scope.category_insert = {
        categoryname: '',
        categorytype: ''
    };
    $scope.categories = ProductService.getCategory();
    $scope.getCategoryProducts = function() {
        $scope.products = ProductService.getCategoryProducts($scope.category_insert.categoryname);
    };
});
app.factory("ProductService", ['$filter', function($filter) {
    this.categoryList = [
        { "id": 1, "category": "ALL MOVIES, TV SHOWS & MUSIC" }//india:1
    ];
    this.productList = [
        {"Id":1, "product":" All Movies and TV Shows", "categoryId": 1},
        {"Id":2, "product":" Video Games", "categoryId": 1},
        {"Id":3, "product":" All Music", "categoryId": 1}
    ];
    this.getCategory = function() {
        return this.categoryList;
    };
    this.getCategoryProducts = function(categoryId) {
        var products = ($filter('filter')(this.productList, {
            categoryId: categoryId
        },true));
        return products;
    };
    return this;
}]);
})();  
Angular code:
    <div class="container login-container">
    <div class="panel">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div ng-if="messages.error" role="alert" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div ng-repeat="error in messages.error">{{error.msg}}</div>
            </div>
<form name="prdctRegister" method="POST" ng-submit="productregstr()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category </label>
        <select ng-model="category_insert.categoryname"
                ng-options="obj.id as obj.category for obj in categories"
                ng-change="getCategoryProducts()"
                class="form-control"
                ng-required="true"
                id="category">
            <option value="">-- Choose Category --</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="product" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product </label>
        <select ng-model="product"
                ng-options="x.Id as x.product for x in products"
                class="form-control"
                ng-required="true"
                id="product">
            <option value="">-- Choose Product --</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-disabled="frmRegister.$invalid">Register</button>

</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What is your problem? please explain it

Comment: how to post data into two tables based on id's..

Comment: based on id's means what? We can post. But you are saying based on id's. Its not clear. Do you want to post a particular item?